# Is it ok for my doors rough opening to not be square if I'm installing a prehung door?

Tags: doors, installation

I have a door rough opening and it isn't square but the sides are level and the top is almost level. I am installing a prehung door and it fits inside the rough opening but it doesn't have an even gap all the way around. Will this be functional and code-compliant after I shim it in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite common for a rough in to be slightly off square.  As long as you shim it properly and anchor it securely, there won't be a problem.